# Regex for filename in path - macos

Tags: java, regex, filepath

I am trying to read a file in my Download folder (I have a mac system) using the below line of code:

```
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("/Users/mohand/Downloads/1963_Automation_BigTurnip_290618.pdf"));
```

The problem is, the numeral "1963" will keep on changing but text "_Automation_BigTurnip_290618.pdf" will remain the same.

Can I use any regex that will pick up any file that has "_Automation_BigTurnip_290618.pdf" ?

Comment: *"Can I use any regex ..."* Yes. --- Well, I guess, once you learn how to write a regex, *you* can... See also: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for regex. Just use [`endsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)):

```
if (name.endsWith("_Automation_BigTurnip_290618.pdf"))
```

Comment: How do i use this in my path name?

Comment: @moh17 Your question is how to do a regex pattern to match file names. I've suggested not to use regex for that. If you really wanted to ask how to scan files in a directory, then you should edit the question and clarify that that is what you need to know. This answer is for the question as it is currently written, i.e. just about name matching.

Answer (score 1):

I did this using :

```
File dir = new File("/Users/mohand/Downloads/");
File[] files = dir.listFiles((dir1, name) ->  name.endsWith("Automation_BigTurnip_290618.pdf"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression like this:

```
^(\d+)_Automation_BigTurnip_290618\.pdf$
```

This would match any file starting with at least one digit and ending in the pattern you specified.

Comment: How do I use this inside my path name as given in the OP?

Comment: @moh17 The path name given in the OP is a hardcoded string, so you don't need a regular expression. Your question makes no sense.